# How to rename an Azure App Service Certificate

Tags: azure, certificate

I've made a mistake in naming an Azure App Service Certificate and can't find any options within the Azure Portal to rename it. The name I gave it doesn't confirm to our naming conventions so I need to correct.

Is there a way to rename a certificate?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't rename the certificate. You need create new one and upload it.

Comment: @OlegShalnov I'm not sure you can create a new one in the "App Service Certificates" service and upload the previously created certificate. There isn't an option for this in the portal.

Comment: In the end I was able to raise a support ticket with Azure, have the certificate refunded and create the new one in the correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot rename existing Azure resources.
You can create a new resource Azure App Service Certificate with new name.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/19048513-rename-resources-in-azure-resource-manager-or-powe